# Why I get "No connection associated with this command"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

My problem is that my datareader didn't works.

Here is my code:

```
SQLiteCommand comID = new SQLiteCommand("Select max(id) from haltestellen");
conSQLiteDb.Open();
SQLiteDataReader dr = comID.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
if (dr.Read())
{
    LblHaltestelleID1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading and understanding the error?

Answer (score 7):

Just use the appropriate constructor. 
The overload that takes as second parameter a connection associate your command to the connection used to perform the required sql statement.

```
 SQLiteCommand comID = new SQLiteCommand("Select max(id) from haltestellen", conSQLiteDb);
 conSQLiteDb.Open();
 SQLiteDataReader dr = comID.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
 if (dr.Read())
 {
    LblHaltestelleID1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
 }
```

You could also use the command property Connection

```
 SQLiteCommand comID = new SQLiteCommand("Select max(id) from haltestellen");
 comID.Connection = conSQLiteDb;
 conSQLiteDb.Open();
```